# Wall plug to usb?

Tags: led, usb, lighting

I’m sure this is not the brightest question. (You’ll see my pun in a minute.) I want to purchase standard plug in strings of LED lights and connect them to USB power banks for events. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Plug-in LED lights, no. These tend to be wired in series and use a higher voltage.

Battery powered (3x AA) LED lights can be connected directly to USB (yes, they're about the same voltage, no worries). I've converted several of these for long-running lights at music festivals.

They also sell USB powered LED strings these days (I spotted them in a craft store for example - Beverly's if you want to know. I recently got a set of faux-Edison lights that run on USB that came from there, and run them on a USB power bank.)

Comment: Thank you!  we are going through way too many batteries & rechargeable are too expensive when you consider 3 per set.

Comment: They sell kits that allow you to insert 'dummy' batteries in place of AAs and power from USB. Search for "usb aa battery eliminator". If you're handy with wiring, hack off a USB cable and wire it into the battery case.